# Android: How to exclude duplicate classes while importing a FAT JAR?

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar, duplicates

After importing a FAT JAR, I have a compilation error:

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kotlin_metadata'
```

The problem is that some classes are duplicated

```
Duplicate class kotlin.ArrayIntrinsicsKt found in modules com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar (com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar) and kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50)
Duplicate class kotlin.BuilderInference found in modules com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar (com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar) and kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50)
Duplicate class kotlin.Deprecated found in modules com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar (com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar) and kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50)
Duplicate class kotlin.DeprecationLevel found in modules com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar (com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar) and kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50)
Duplicate class kotlin.DslMarker found in modules com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar (com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar) and kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50)
Duplicate class kotlin.ExceptionsKt found in modules com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar (com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar) and kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50)
Duplicate class kotlin.ExceptionsKt__ExceptionsKt found in modules com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar (com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar) and kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50)
Duplicate class kotlin.Experimental found in modules com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar (com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar) and kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50)
Duplicate class kotlin.Experimental$Level found in modules com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar (com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar) and kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50)
...
```

My question is, how can I exclude some classes from a FAT JAR file.
I tried:

```
implementation files('libs/com.fiskaly.kassensichv.client-android-0.0.1-alpha-all.jar'){
        exclude group: 'kotlin'
    }
```

But it returns an error because a file based dependency does not work in the same way as a dependency coming from a repository. There is no meta data associated with it (eg no dependency information) so there's also nothing to exclude (since there's no transitive dependencies).